# Keyboard doesn't work after closing lid. Running Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: keyboard, suspend, touchpad, power-management, laptop

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 on a Sony VAIO VGN-CS320J. Bear in mind, I am a complete newbie, and know very little about this, so pardon my incompetence.

The touchpad still works after re-opening the lid, but nothing makes the keyboard work. I've tried every combination of buttons as well.

I also tried replacing a certain line of code (I forgot which but I assure you, I had the right line) with the following code:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.dumbkbd=1"
```

then updated and saved as other forums said to do. The problem arises when I used

```
sudo update-grub
```

I get the following message:

```
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: ^#: not found
```

It's really, really frustrating.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/default/grub`? Read `man update-grub`. While you're beginning your Linux journey, keep track of what changes you make to your system, in enough detail so that you can undo your changes. For example, if I told you (I'm NOT telling you) that you should undo your change to "I also tried replacing a certain line of code (I forgot which but I assure you, I had the right line)"? Don't reply via Add comment, rather [edit] your question. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: It appears that you edited /etc/default/grub but you made a mistake - the error message says that something is wrong with that file.  So whatever the change you made was supposed to do, it's not doing anything, the change did not get incorporated. If you post the contents of the file in your question as requested, someone will help you fix it.

Comment: Indeed, likely a typo from your part. To post the contents of the file, open the editor, hit Ctrl+O to open a file, and in the file dialog, select  "Other locations" in the left pane, , then in the right pane navigate to `Computer`, then `etc`, then `default`, where you find the file `grub`. You will open it read-only this way, and you can paste the contents of the file in your question here.